# Select 2 columns in one and combine them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

Is it possible to select 2 columns in just one and combine them?

Example:

`select something + somethingElse as onlyOneColumn from someTable`

Comment: It's unclear whether you are wanting to operate on two values (like make a "Joe Smith" and "Jane Doe" full name result from first+last name columns) or whether you want a union of all results like "Joe", "Jane", "Smith", "Doe".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, just like you did:

```
select something + somethingElse as onlyOneColumn from someTable
```

If you queried the database, you would have gotten the right answer.

What happens is you ask for an expression. A very simple expression is just a column name, a more complicated expression can have formulas etc in it.

Answer (score 62):

```
(SELECT column1 as column FROM table )
UNION 
(SELECT column2 as column FROM table )
```

Answer (score 49):

Yes,

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, field2) AS WHOLENAME FROM TABLE
WHERE ...
```

will result in data set like:

```
WHOLENAME
field1field2
```

Answer (score 35):

None of the other answers worked for me but this did:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Cust_First, ' ', Cust_Last) AS CustName FROM customer
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes it's possible, as long as the datatypes are compatible. If they aren't, use a CONVERT() or CAST()

```
SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname AS name FROM customers
```

Comment: this not worked  correct for me in SQLite if firstname and lastname were strings but as @user1313900 answered you must user || to concat two strings of two columns

Answer (score 12):

The `+` operator should do the trick just fine. Keep something in mind though, if one of the columns is null or does not have any value, it will give you a `NULL` result. Instead, combine `+` with the function `COALESCE` and you'll be set.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1,'') + COALESCE(column2,'') FROM table1.
```

For this example, if `column1` is `NULL`, then the results of `column2` will show up, instead of a simple `NULL`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

To complete the answer of @Pete Carter, I would add an "ALL" on the UNION (if you need to keep the duplicate entries).

(SELECT column1 as column FROM table )

UNION ALL

(SELECT column2 as column FROM table )

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #9
    CREATE TABLE #9 
(
    USER1 int
    ,USER2 int
)
INSERT INTO #9
 VALUES(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3)
 ------------------------------------------------
(SELECT USER1 AS 'column' from #9)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT USER2 AS 'column' from #9)
```

Would then return : [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyWQ7.png)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can combine columns easily enough such as concatenating character data:

```
select col1 | col 2 as bothcols from tbl ...
```

or adding (for example) numeric data:

```
select col1 + col2 as bothcols from tbl ...
```

In both those cases, you end up with a single column `bothcols`, which contains the combined data. You may have to coerce the data type if the columns are not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

if one of the column is number i have experienced the oracle will think '+' as sum operator instead concatenation.

eg:

```
select (id + name) as one from table 1; (id is numeric)
```

throws invalid number exception

in such case you can || operator which is concatenation.

```
select (id || name) as one from table 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer helps:

```
SELECT (CAST(id AS NVARCHAR)+','+name) AS COMBINED_COLUMN FROM TABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should work, maybe add a space between the colums like

`SELECT something + ' ' + somethingElse as onlyOneColumn FROM someTable`

Comment: This would only work if something & somethingElse are both strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1 || ' ' || column2 as whole_name FROM tablename;
```

Here `||` is the concat operator used for concatenating them to single column and (`''`) inside `||` used for space between two columns.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT firstname || ' ' || lastname FROM users;
```