# How to merge two columns using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table:

```
id    foo    bar
 1    a      d
 2    b      e
 3    c      f
```

I want to merge the foo and bar colum so that I have result set of all their values:

Expected result:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

My search yielded [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5340064/457268) yet its answer are about concatting the fields via:

```
select CONCAT(foo, bar) as foobar from MyTable
```

Producing the wrong output for me:

```
ad
be
cf
```

I don't want to concat but  I want to merge the two columns.

How can I get a result of all the values of the `foo` bar two fields?

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT foo as new_col FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT bar FROM MyTable
```

Or `UNION ALL` if you're intrested in duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use Union all

```
      Select foo from a
        Union all
      Select bar from a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION ALL:

```
select foo from tablename
union all
select bar from tablename
```

Comment: What's the difference compared to just using `UNION`?

Comment: union all will give you duplicate also and union discard the duplicate value, but in your sample data there is no duplicate value so union and union all give you same result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT foo FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT bar FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

what about...

```
select foo from TABLE UNION ALL select bar from TABLE
```