# I want to print same values in column

Tags: mysql, datatable

[image]

Here I want to print in column img_parent_id , it's value as  img_id 's column data

I need values in column img_parent_id as
12
12
14
12
14
16 like column img_id

I am begineer in this  Help me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try to show the minimum effort, like what have you tried to do in order to find a solution before posting the question. Then, re-post with a question. Regards.

Comment: [Select 2 columns in one and combine them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340064/select-2-columns-in-one-and-combine-them) Please, visit this link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select 2 columns in one and combine them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340064/select-2-columns-in-one-and-combine-them)

Comment: I dont want to union

Comment: i need same data for api linking to android app

Comment: I need separate column

Comment: Okay, then follow the instructions of the following link. [Data of 2 columns in a new seperate column](https://simplernerd.com/sql-combine-columns/).

Comment: question edited just now

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is about an alias, if so it is solved in this way

```
SELECT img_id as img_paret_id, img_id, img_path, cat_id
FROM table
```